# How to avoid Nonetype when combining lists in Python

Tags: python, list, split, nonetype

I am very new to Python and am looking for assistance to where I am going wrong with an assignment. I have attempted different ways to approach the problem but keep getting stuck at the same point(s):

Problem 1: When I am trying to create a list of words from a file, I keep making a list for the words per line rather than the entire file

Problem 2: When I try and combine the lists I keep receiving "None" for my result or Nonetype errors [which I think means I have added the None's together(?)].

The assignment is:

```
#8.4 Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/romeo.txt
```

My current code which is giving me a Nonetype error is:

```
poem = input("enter file:")
play = open(poem)
lst= list()
for line in play:
    line=line.rstrip()
    word=line.split()
    if not word in lst:
        lst= lst.append(word)
print(lst.sort())
```

If someone could just talk me through where I am going wrong that will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your error is here: `lst= lst.append(word)`. `append` alters the list itself and returns `None`. Just use `lst.append(word)`.

Comment: Thank you, I attempted this but it now seems like my first problem is occurring where I am now combining the four separate lists but not the strings within them into one new list....

Comment: There's an error regarding your condition. You have `word=line.split()`. The name "word" is misleading, because you get a list of "words". So use `words = line.split()` and add a loop with `for word in words:`.

Comment: BTW, `print(lst.sort())` has the same problem as your usage of `append`. `sort` sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. So you need two lines: `lst.sort()` and `print(lst)`.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to fix it! Your guidance helped greatly!

Answer (score 1):

*Problem 1: When I am trying to create a list of words from a file, I keep making a list for the words per line rather than the entire file*

You are doing `play = open(poem)` then `for line in play:` which is method for processing file line-by-line, if you want to process whole content at once then do:

```
play = open(poem)
content = play.read()
words = content.split()
```

Please always remember to `close` file after you used it i.e. do

```
play.close()
```

unless you use context manager way (i.e. like `with open(poem) as f:`)

Answer (score 0):

your problem was `lst= lst.append(word)` this returns `None`

```
with open(poem) as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n') #you can also you readlines()

lst = []
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word:
            lst.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to help you get into Python a little more:

You can:
1. Read whole file at once (if it is big it is better to grab it into RAM if you have enough of it, if not grab as much as you can for the chunk to be reasonable, then grab another one and so on)
2. Split data you read into words and
3. Use set() or dict() to remove duplicates

Along the way, you shouldn't forget to pay attention to upper and lower cases,
if you need same words, not just different not repeating strings

This will work in Py2 and Py3 as long as you do something about input() function in Py2 or use quotes when entering the path, so:

```
path = input("Filename: ")
f = open(filename)
c = f.read()
f.close()
words = set(x.lower() for x in c.split()) # This will make a set of lower case words, with no repetitions
# This equals to:
#words = set()
#for x in c.split():
#    words.add(x.lower())
# set() is an unordered datatype ignoring duplicate items
# and it mimics mathematical sets and their properties (unions, intersections, ...)
# it is also fast as hell.
# Checking a list() each time for existance of the word is slow as hell
#----
# OK, you need a sorted list, so:
words = sorted(words)
# Or step-by-step:
#words = list(words)
#words.sort()
# Now words is your list
```

As for your errors, do not worry, they are common at the beginning in almost any objective oriented language.
Other explained them well in their comments. But not to make the answer lacking...:

Always pay attention on functions or methods which operate on the datatype (in place sort - list.sort(), list.append(), list.insert(), set.add()...) and which ones return a new version of the datatype (sorted(), str.lower()...).
If you ran into a similar situation again, use help() in interactive shell to see what exactly a function you used does.

```
>>> help(list.append)
>>> help(list.sort)
>>> help(str.lower)
>>> # Or any short documentation you need
```

Python, especially Python 3.x is sensitive to trying operations between types, but some might have a different connotation and can actually work while doing unexpected stuff.
E.g. you can do:

```
print(40*"x")
```

It will print out 40 'x' characters, because it will create a string of 40 characters.
But:

```
print([1, 2, 3]+None)
```

will, logically not work, which is what is happening somewhere in the rest of your code.

In some languages like javascript (terrible stuff) this will work perfectly well:

```
v = "abc "+123+" def";
```

Inserting the 123 seamlessly into the string. Which is usefull, but a programming nightmare and nonsense from another viewing angle.

Also, in Py3 a reasonable assumption from Py2 that you can mix unicode and byte strings and that automatic cast will be performed is not holding.
I.e. this is a TypeError:

```
print(b"abc"+"def")
```

because b"abc" is bytes() and "def" (or u"def") is str() in Py3 - what is unicode() in Py2)

Enjoy Python, it is the best!